# Postback values getting lost!

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, post, controller, strong-typing

I have a controller with typical *create* methods (one for GET, one for POST).  the POST takes a strongly-typed parameter:

```
[HttpPost] public ActionResult Create(Quiz entity)
```

however, when the callback is made, the properties of my entity are null... if I redefine it like this:

```
[HttpPost] public ActionResult Create(Quiz entity, FormCollection form)
```

I can see that the values are there e.g. `form["Component"]` contains `"1"`.  I've not had this problem in the past and I can't figure out why this class would be different.

thoughts anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I FIGURED IT OUT!!

so, in my model (see comments on @ataddeini's thread below) you can see I have a Component... to represent components I used a couple of listboxes, the second (Components) dependent on the contents of the first (Products). In generating the second list I used

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Component, ...)
```

which (as shown in one of the above links) generates a form field called "Component"... and therein lies the problem. What I needed to have done is bind it to the the Id of the component instead!

```
@Html.DropDowListFor(x => x.Component.Id, ...)
```

hurray!

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to get the default model binder to instantiate `Quiz` for you on postback is to use the Html form helpers in you view.  So, for example, if your `Quiz` class looked like this:

```
public class Quiz
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The following code in your view would ensure the values are present on postback:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(mod => mod.Id)
@Html.TextBoxFor(mod => mod.Name)
```

Keep in mind that values which need to be posted back but not shown in the view (like identifiers) need to be added to the view with `Html.HiddenFor`.

[Here's a more comprehensive list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410596.aspx) of Html form helper functions.

Comment: @ataddeini, I _am_ using the @Html helpers to build the view, and my class was generated by EF, just like all the other classes.  I really don't get what the issue here may be...

Comment: @ekkis: OK.  If you can provide the view markup and more of the controller code I'd be happy to take a closer look.

Comment: @ataddeini, the code is rather unremarkable.  I think what may be happening is that I'm mixing domains... I have a controller to handle products which contains methods to create/edit/delete/etc.  however, I'm also creating methods there to manage other entities e.g. ProductType - is that essentially bad design, should I have a controller for product types, or is it a reasonable approach to have a single controller that handles many types of entities?  could that be why the /entity/ isn't getting populated?

Comment: hmm... there is one issue that might be of interest.  the form that's posted to the controller method is done via ajax.  here's the code it generates:

Comment: `<form action="/Question/Create" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="Post" id="form0" method="post"><div class="display-label">Level</div><div class="display-field">
<select id="Questions_0__Level_Level" name="Questions[0].Level.Level"><option selected="selected" value="1">Basic</option><option value="2">Intermediate</option><option value="3">Advanced</option></select></div><div class="display-field"><textarea class="text-box multi-line" id="Questions_0__Text" name="Questions[0].Text">
</textarea></div><button class="add">Add</button>
</form>`

Comment: @ataddeini, incidentally, I moved the method to its own controller but it didn't help.  I still have the problem that the values are available if I declare a FormCollection parameter but not if I strongly type it...

Comment: one thing you might note is the format of the field names... they are generated with a .DisplayFor() which traverses through a collection.  inspired by the thought I recoded the method's signature as: `[HttpPost] public ActionResult Create(IList<Question> entities ...` but to no avail.  now the parameter is just null

Comment: @ekkis: Yeah, the controller organization shouldn't be a factor.  I'm starting to wonder if you're running into an issue with how the default model binder instantiates the model on post back.  Can you post your model class structure?

Comment: @ataddeini, by "model class structure", do you mean the definition of Quiz?  it's an EF generated class, looks like:

Comment: `namespace Website.Models
{
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
    
  public partial class Quiz
  {
    public Quiz()
    {
        this.Questions = new HashSet<Question>();
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Question> Questions { get; set; }
    public virtual Employer Employer { get; set; }
    public virtual Component Component { get; set; }
    public virtual Requirement Requirement { get; set; }
    public virtual Score Score { get; set; }
    public virtual Skill Skill { get; set; }
  }
}`

Comment: @ekkis: I don't know what to tell you, but something seems to be messing up the default model binder (possibly the instantiation of the `Hashset<Question>()` in the constructor) and I'd really need to step into the code to debug it.  I would recommend removing the properties one by one, with the ID being last, until you get it to work.  Then at least you could hopefully get some clues.

Comment: it's really finicky.  I've got it working but I'm not sure what I did (I've tried so many things).  I guess the thing is naming of fields on a form is really important

Comment: @ekkis: Yeah, that is important--there are conventions with how form elements render (like the id `Questions_0__Level_Level` above) that determines how the model binder is able to instantiate the model on postback.  Glad you were able to figure it out.

Comment: @ataddeini, I got back to this.  the way I had "resolved" was by using a FormCollection (only because I couldn't otherwise make it work).  Here is the HTML code that my view is generating: http://pastebin.com/yytLHiAt and my controller and class: http://pastebin.com/ZxL08UZt - when I run it, the /entity/ argument passed to the controller is an object with all null values.  The naming of the fields on the form looks right... what else could it be? (incidentally, there are no exceptions thrown and nothing written to the Output window)

Comment: @ataddeini, one more thing, here's the GET Create method that calls the view.  I'm not sure it's all that relevant but I'm starting to believe so: http://pastebin.com/wktiFa10